Langchain cvs agent parsing
I am testing a csv agent using a Hugging Face model locally with the titanic dataset. The code is straightforward:
from langchain_experimental.agents import create_csv_agent
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM, pipeline
# from langchain.llms.huggingface_pipeline import HuggingFacePipeline
from langchain_community.llms import HuggingFacePipeline
# from langchain_huggingface import HuggingFacePipeline
from config import set_environment
import os


def main():
    set_environment()

    local_model_path = '../models/bling-sheared-llama-1.3b-0.1/'

    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(local_model_path)
    model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(local_model_path, device_map = 'cuda')

    local_pipeline = pipeline('text-generation', model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer, max_length=2000) 
    llm = HuggingFacePipeline(pipeline=local_pipeline)

    #______________________________
    agent = create_csv_agent(
    llm, "titanic.csv", verbose=True, handle_parsing_errors=True)
    
    user_question = "How many rows are there?"
    response = agent.invoke(user_question)
    print(response)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

This returns the following error even though I've added the handle_parsing_errors argument to the agent executor:

ValueError: An output parsing error occurred. In order to pass this
error back to the agent and have it try again, pass
handle_parsing_errors=True to the AgentExecutor. This is the error:
Parsing LLM output produced both a final answer and a parse-able
action

How does one proceed?
